# I'm trying to create a student organizer in Java 1.4.2 for a project, but I seem to be stumped

Tags: java, syntax

I recycled some old code for this project, but I double checked that all the integers and strings were redefined for this project. Can you guys let me know what I'm doing wrong? I am not very good at programming. The errors I'm getting include 'sort', 'display'and 'print' can't be applied to (`java.lang.String[],int[],java.io,BufferedReader`). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited: here is the stacktrace

```
C:\java\bin>javac CourseOrganizer.java
CourseOrganizer.java:23: getdata(int[],java.lang.String[],int) in CourseOrganize
r cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[])
        getdata(Grade,Course);
        ^
CourseOrganizer.java:28: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : method display (int[],java.lang.String[],java.io.BufferedReader)
location: class CourseOrganizer
        display(Grade,Course,in);
        ^
CourseOrganizer.java:34: sort(int[],java.lang.String[],int,java.io.BufferedReade
r) in CourseOrganizer cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[],java.io.Buf
feredReader)
        sorttype=sort(Grade,Course,in);
                 ^
CourseOrganizer.java:87: sortstring(int[],java.lang.String[],int) in CourseOrgan
izer cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[])
     {sortstring(Grade,Course);
      ^
CourseOrganizer.java:88: print(int[],java.lang.String[],int,java.io.BufferedRead
er) in CourseOrganizer cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[],java.io.Bu
fferedReader)
      print(Grade,Course,kb);
      ^
CourseOrganizer.java:92: sortint(int[],java.lang.String[],int) in CourseOrganize
r cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[])
     {sortint(Grade,Course);
      ^
CourseOrganizer.java:93: print(int[],java.lang.String[],int,java.io.BufferedRead
er) in CourseOrganizer cannot be applied to (int[],java.lang.String[],java.io.Bu
fferedReader)
      print(Grade,Course,kb);
      ^
7 errors
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class CourseOrganizer {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
InputStreamReader kb = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(kb);   
String buffer;
char choice;
boolean fileread=false;
int quantity=8;
int[]Grade=new int[quantity];
String[]Course=new String[quantity];
String sorttype="";
do
//Setup Menu
{choice=menu(in);
if(choice=='E')
   {if(fileread)
        System.out.println("Data already has been entered");
     else
        {fileread=true;
        getdata(Grade,Course);
         }
    }
else if(choice=='D')
    {if(fileread)
        display(Grade,Course,in);
     else
        System.out.println("Must enter data before it is displayed");
         }
else if(choice=='S')
    {if(fileread)
        sorttype=sort(Grade,Course,in);
     else
        System.out.println("Must enter data before it is sorted");
    }


}while(choice!='X');
}
//Sort Data
public static void sortint(int Grade[],String Course[],int quantity)
{int i,j;
for(i=0;i<quantity-1;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<quantity;j++)
         if(Grade[i]>Grade[j])
              {swap(Grade,i,j);
                swap(Course,i,j);

                }
}
public static void sortstring(int Grade[],String Course[],int quantity)
{int i,j;
for(i=0;i<quantity-1;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<quantity;j++)
         if(Course[i].compareToIgnoreCase(Course[j])>0)
              {swap(Grade,i,j);
                swap(Course,i,j);

                }
}
public static void swap(int[] a,int i,int j)
{int t;
t=a[i];
a[i]=a[j];
a[j]=t;
}
public static void swap(String[] a,int i,int j)
{String t;
t=a[i];
a[i]=a[j];
a[j]=t;
}

public static String sort(int Grade[],String Course[],int quantity,BufferedReader kb)throws Exception
{String buffer;
do
{
//Allow user to sort the criminals
System.out.println("What do you want to sort by?");
System.out.println("Course");
System.out.println("Grade");
System.out.print("Enter>>");
buffer=kb.readLine();
if(buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Course"))
     {sortstring(Course,Grade);
      print(Course,Grade,kb);
      return buffer;
      }
else if(buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Grade"))
     {sortint(Course,Grade);
      print(Course,Grade,kb);
      return buffer;
      }

System.out.println("Invalid entry");
}while(true);

}
public static String gettype(BufferedReader kb)throws Exception
{String buffer;
do
{
//Allow users to search for course
System.out.println("What course would you like to see?");
System.out.print("Enter>>");
buffer=kb.readLine();
if(buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Calculus")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Advanced Functions")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Computer Science")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Physics")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Biology")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Chemistry")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("History")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("English")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Economics")||buffer.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Management"))
     return buffer;
System.out.println("Invalid entry");
}while(true);
}
public static void print(int Grade[],String Course[],int quantity,BufferedReader kb)throws Exception
{System.out.println("Sorted data");
System.out.println("Grade\tCourse");
for(int i=0;i<quantity;i++)
        System.out.println(Grade[i]+"\t"+Course[i]);
}
//Load criminal text file
public static void getdata(int Grade[],String Course[],int quantity)throws Exception
{FileReader file = new FileReader("courses.txt");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);
int i;
String buffer;
for( i=0;i<quantity;i++)
  {buffer=input.readLine();
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(buffer, ",");
   Course[i]=st.nextToken();
   Grade[i]=Integer.parseInt((st.nextToken()).trim());
    }
input.close();
}

public static char menu(BufferedReader kb)throws Exception
{String buffer;
char input;
do
{
System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
System.out.println("E-Enter course data");
System.out.println("D-Display course data");
System.out.println("X-Exit program");
System.out.println("S-Sort list");
System.out.print("Enter E, D, X, S>>");
buffer=kb.readLine();
input=(buffer.toUpperCase()).charAt(0);
if(input=='E'||input=='D'||input=='X'||input=='S')
     return input;
System.out.println("Invalid entry");
}while(true);
```

Comment: what is the question are you getting an error? please post only relevant code

Comment: PLease post the stacktrace.

Comment: give us the whole stacktrace pls and the line

Comment: clearly the errors you are getting indicate what is wrong with your code. Trace through how you pass the arguments to the functions, it will become evident.. (hint: you are declaring the functions to expect arguments in a particular order, but when you are calling them, you mix the order of the arguments...)

Answer (score 2):

> 'sort', [...] can't be applied to (java.lang.String[],int[],java.io,BufferedReader)

That's pretty reasonable, because `sort` has another signature:

```
int Grade[], String Course[], int quantity, BufferedReader kb)
```

If you notice, `sort` expects an `int[]` to be its first argument and a `String[]` to be its second. So, go wherever you call it and change the order of the arguments you pass. This is probably the reason why the other methods show this error as well.